# Copy object - keep polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, polymorphism

The following code tries to copy an object and keep the original type.
Unfortunately it does not work (every copied object will become a `Super` instead of being of the same class as its original).

Please note that `copySuper(const Super& givenSuper)` should not know anything about the subclasses of `Super`.

Is it possible to do such a copy? Or do I have to change the definition of `copySuper` ?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Super
{
public:
    Super() {};
    virtual ~Super() {};

    virtual std::string toString() const
    {
        return "I'm Super!";
    }
};

class Special : public Super
{
public:
    Special() {};
    virtual ~Special() {};

    virtual std::string toString() const
    {
        return "I'm Special!";
    }
};

Super* copySuper(const Super& givenSuper)
{
    Super* superCopy( new Super(givenSuper) );
    return superCopy;
}

int main()
{
    Special special;
    std::cout << special.toString() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;

    Super* specialCopy = copySuper(special);
    std::cout << specialCopy->toString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

//Desired Output:
// # I'm Special!
// # ---
// # I'm Special!
//
//Actual Output:
// # I'm Sepcial!
// # ---
// # I'm Super!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy constructor needs to call a method that depends on the object, but constructor can't be virtual.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032109/copy-constructor-needs-to-call-a-method-that-depends-on-the-object-but-construct)

Comment: This should not compile because there is at least one constructor specified, but not a copy constructor.

Comment: This compiles at least with VS 2008

Comment: You're right. Me confused. Oh well, nothing new.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Super
{
public:
    Super();// regular ctor
    Super(const Super& _rhs); // copy constructor
    virtual Super* clone() const {return(new Super(*this));};
}; // eo class Super


class Special : public Super
{
public:
    Special() : Super() {};
    Special(const Special& _rhs) : Super(_rhs){};
    virtual Special* clone() const {return(new Special(*this));};
}; // eo class Special
```

Note that we have implemented a clone() function that Special (and any other derivative of Super) overrides to create the correct copy.

e.g:

```
Super* s = new Super();
Super* s2 = s->clone(); // copy of s
Special* a = new Special();
Special* b = a->clone(); // copy of a
```

EDIT: As other commentator pointed out, `*this`, not `this`.  That'll teach me to type quickly.

EDIT2: Another correction.

EDIT3: I really should not post so quickly when in the middle of work.  Modified return-type of Special::clone() for covariant return-types.

Comment: Precisely what I was about to say...+1

Comment: @Moo: Also correct this line. 
Special* b = b->clone(); // copy of a
It should be a->clone();

Comment: one more thing. Your code will not compile, because of this line 'Super();/ regular ctor'

Comment: I can't take the blame for that one, I'm afraid.  I swear the editor screws with me sometimes, as that was correct on posting.  Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: +1, though I would put the copy constructor and assignment operator as `protected` in every object because their unintentional use might lead to object slicing. I would also note that `return` being a keyword and not a function, there is a couple of extra parenthesis that we could do without.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: you could simplify the example by not using `new`, it's perfectly fine to instantiate the objects on the stack and I am afraid it may obscure more than help to have so many pointers. Also it would be better to use smart pointers for `s2` and `b` so as to show that even if the memory is returned by a dumb pointer (to exploit covariance) the caller is required to manage the memory and very strongly advised NOT to try to manage it manually (and fail).

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need :

```
class Super
{
    public:
        Super()
        {
        }

        virtual Super* clone() const
        {
            return( new Super(*this) );
        };
};


class Special : public Super
{
    public:
        Special() : Super()
        {
        };
        Special(const Special& _rhs) : Super(_rhs)
        {
        };
        virtual Special* clone() const
        {
            return( new Special( *this ) );
        };
};

int main()
{
    Special a;
    Super &c( a );
    Super *b1 = c.clone();
    Special *b2 = a.clone();
    Super *b3 = a.clone();
}
```

One of previous examples has the clone for derived class wrong. The above is correct way of implementing the clone method.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Your Special::clone() method returns Super*, which is wrong. The correct return for Special::clone() is Special*

Comment: This will definitely teach me to post hastily, many thanks.  I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is generally implemented using an abstract `clone` method in the base class. Special will typically implement this method by returning `new Special(*this)`.

Also note that it is considered a best practice to make base classes uncopyable.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, this is in the C++ FAQ:

http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/mirror/c++-faq/abcs.html#faq-22.5